# Как аннотировать неизвестные заранее библиотеки (модули) при написании TypeScript-типов?

Tags: typescript

В приведённом ниже определении типов к [gulp-postcss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-postcss) на месте `parser?: Object;` может быть любая npm-библиотека. Как её правильно аннотировать?

```
/// <reference types="node"/>
import Vinyl = require('vinyl');

declare function GulpPostCss(plugins?: string[], options?: GulpPostCss.Options): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream;
declare function GulpPostCss(callback?: (file: Vinyl) => { plugins?: string[], options?: GulpPostCss.Options }):
    NodeJS.ReadWriteStream;

declare namespace GulpPostCss {
    interface Options {
        parser?: Object;
    }
}

export = GulpPostCss;
```

Естественно, что `any` или `Object` - это решение, допускающееся лишь в тех случаях, когда никаких других нет (тем более, что [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) не принимает тип `Object`, и правильно делает).

Comment: а почему вас смущает `any` для описания "__ЛЮБАЯ__ npm-библиотека"?

Comment: @ThisMan, потому что `any` позволяет впихнуть число или boolean вместо библиотеки.